# Objective C syntax paradigm

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I am fairly new with Objective C and getting my feet wet! I have came across with two different notations in syntax,

1. Dot notation
2. Square bracket notation

I would like to ask, Which would be more preferable? As I am learning this straight after java I am much more familiar with dot notation. So should consider it to be a normal pattern for whatever code I write? Does industry standardised which notation to use?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot notation is only available for properties and of course C structs. Whether you prefer:

```
foo.aProperty = bar.anotherProperty;
```

or:

```
[foo setAProperty:[bar anotherProperty]];
```

...is a matter of taste. I personally prefer the second one because it's absolutely clear there's two method calls involved. You can't tell at a first glance in this case:

```
CGFloat x = myView.frame.origin.x;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
CGFloat x = [myView frame].origin.x;
```

In the second example, it's clearly visible that a method call is involved, but the first example tends to be more readable.

So use whichever suits you, both are okay (though I guess most developers tend to use the first one, partly due to the fact it's faster to type and tends to be more legible).

Comment: I would consider using dot for properties and brackets for method, Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Use dot notation to refer to properties and square notation to call methods. Both result in a message send, but at least you are separating state vs behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Well if I am not wrong, the `square notation` is more native. This is what was more prevalent.
The `dot notation` has come into being recently.

I have seen code with both styles being used...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any standard but I prefer the "Square bracket notation" for calling methods and the "dot notation" for accessing properties. Though the dot notation works the same, it helps differentiate between the two operations